# Need help with Controlling WS2812B LEDS

Tags: python, led

I have made a 5 x 5 WS2812B RGB LED matrix to work with my raspberry pi. 
I'm trying to figure out how to run several tests from this tutorial: 
https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/connect-control-raspberry-pi-ws2812-rgb-led-strips/

Here is how I connected it: 
GRND to pin 6(B&W cables) 
the 5v to pin 2 (R&GREY cables)
din to pin 12(GPIO18 as references)(Y&B cables)

when I connect the 5v and the GRND to raspberry pi 3b+ they light up very 
bright (not running any code yet)

installing the rpi_ws281x library and running strandtest.py doesn't do anything to the less.it feels to me like the software isn't connecting to the LEDS since it only shines white without any software anyway.

anybody have any idea what could be wrong here?

some foto's for references:

[image]

[image]

When I connect GRND + 5V:

[image]

when running the code it stays white: 
[image]

here is the strandtest.py config: 
[image]

Thank you very much for your time,

Juriaan

Comment: What happens when you run strandtest.py?

Comment: Have you configured the proper number of LEDs and other config variables in strandtest.py?

Comment: I have updated my post. the first foto is what happens, the tests seem to be running normally, but no responds on the LEDS. In the strand test.py file I changed the Grid number to 25. and I tried adjusting brightness from 255 to 120 but also no change.

Comment: Try a different DMA channel, like 8. DON'T TRY 5. Also, make sure the connection is good

Comment: Ok I'm about to try out different dma channel's can I use all except 5?

Comment: Also, you don't need to follow everything in the tutorial. Just install python ws281x with `sudo pip3 install rpi_ws281x` and then TRY python3 - `sudo python3 strandtest.py`

Comment: you are definatly right on that part. do you have any tuts on python 3 leds?

Comment: No it's easy. Just do `sudo python3 strandtest.py` instead of using `python`

Comment: It displaysL " name error: name "adafruit_neopixel" is not defined

Comment: 1. **DO NOT** post pictures of code - post text.

Comment: 2. You appear to be powering the strips from 5V, but controlling them from 3.3V. Use a level converter - WS2812B are unreliable with lower voltages.

Comment: thank you for your tips, I have ordered a level converter will continue when it's here.